# Showing no time on the plot but showing the correct date

Tags: python, matplotlib

Not getting a time on the plot but date is plotting correctly, have checked the list `dateIndex` is showing all the time.
The output plot looks like this:

[image: xaxis]

```
def graphData(dateIndex,irValue,mar):

    dateIndex.pop() #take out the empty string
    irValue.pop()  #equalising the size

    avgData = movingaverage(irValue,mar)
    spLen = len(dateIndex[mar-1:])

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    date = mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    datenum = [date(i) for i in dateIndex] # date function here.

    ax1.plot(datenum[-spLen:], avgData[-spLen:])
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(20))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d \n %H:%M:%S'))

    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
            label.set_rotation(45)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: You _are_ getting times.  The ticks are at midnight every 5 days, which is what you told it to do.

Comment: Hi @tcaswell tried to change the ticks but no use, still it is showing the midnight time, is there any way change it to get time display as normal, thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your help @tcaswell, have changed the format to display, now it works, thanks...

Comment: If you solved your problem can you please answer your own question (and accept the answer when the system will let you)?  I am glad you got it to work (I don't really understand what you were trying to day).